# where doesthe F come from in this lick?

Tags: guitar

So, I've got this lick:
[image]

Most of the notes fall on the C major pentatonic, but there's an F note that I don't know where it's coming from.

As fingered on the tab, it fits even this pattern (d major pattern from CAGED) and the main notes are played on the D major triad notes.

[image]

So, from a theory point of view. How do we describe this lick? (More precisely, that F note, where is it coming from?)

Comment: If you repeat the first half of the second bar, what does it sound like to you?

Comment: What piece is this from? It looks like it's from an etude (the 2nd system/line looks like an augmentation of the 1st), so I think the piece's name may provide massive clues.

Comment: "I've got this lick..." do you mean you made up this lick? The F came from whoever made the lick.

Comment: What are the chords?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question here is "Why would this piece/excerpt that otherwise slavishly uses the C major/A minor pentatonic scale include F's?"...which is not basic analysis, IMO. I don't think the question asker cares what key the excerpt is in - it could stay in one key or change back and forth, and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I'm not sure if I get your point. The opening lick of the solo of "Stairways to heaven" follows A minor pentatonic, but ends up on the F note. Why? Because the chord changes to Fmaj7. Without knowing such context it's hard to provide a substantial answer.

Comment: @user1079505 - My point is that I do not think closing this question because it is a "basic analysis question" is justified. This isn't a "What key is this piece/excerpt in?" question, it's a "why include this note outside the initial pentatonic scale used?" question. This is even more restrictive than asking for the key, and our answers should respect this.

Comment: @Dekkadeci SE doesn't show it, but the reason I (and I think one more person) voted was "needs more details". Without these details a good answer to a "why" question can't be provided.

Answer (score 6):

A "theory" explanation?

It's notated with a `F` major/`D` minor key signature. Why would an `F` in the passage be confusing when it would be either the major tonic or minor mediant, or simply because it's diatonic to the key signature.

I think the question is: why are you trying to shoe-horn the passage into a pentatonic scale?

There is absolutely no reason to think that if a passage doesn't conform to a pentatonic scale it needs a special explanation.

Instead of trying to understand licks (which theory-wise is essentially melody) look at things through melodic fundamentals.

The passage does things like outline triads, or decorates triads with various non-chord tones, and it also uses neighbor/auxiliary motion in a few places, overall it seems to me to work around `Am` and `Dm` triad tones, so from a tonality point of view that places it roughly in the *modal* region of the key signature, it does not emphatically move within *tonal* keys of either `F` major or `D` minor. The melodic contour uses a few "arch" patterns within an overall descending line.

Something like that is how to evaluate a melodic line and how the line works, rather than trying to explain away why it doesn't fit into a CAGED pentatonic "box."

Is the line supposed to be based on pentatonic patterns, like an etude as some answers suggest? Maybe. If it is, then a good teaching book should indicate the point of the exercise.

But, you can also, think about this: a pentatonic scale can be viewed as simply triadic tones with two auxiliary tones - a neighbor tone and a passing tone - the placement of those two depends on whether it's a major or minor pentatonic scale. A lot of pentatonic line dwell around those triadic tones and shift back and forth between either the major or minor triad and its relative major/minor. So, with a `C` major pentatonic scale you have `C E G` triadic tones, and auxiliary tone `A` and passing tone `D`, if the line shifts toward the relative minor you then have triadic tones `A C E` with auxiliary `G` and passing tone `D`. The point here is just to make clear the importance of triadic tones to pentatonic lines and to melody generally.

A lot of pentatonic lines imply a harmony that drifts between two relative chords in that way. But, other times a melody dwells on a pentatonic selection of tones, but then to work with tonal harmony the melody moves to other tones of a diatonic scale. An example is the song *Oh Susanna.* In cases like that the music isn't really pentatonic. The pentatonic aspect is superficial and can be easily explained as triadic decoration. The melodic movement to tones beyond a pentatonic scale show the music is actually using the full diatonic gamut of tones.

Sorry for the long digression. I'm just trying to encourage you to look deeper into what is truly pentatonic music and that which is only superficially pentatonic-like patterns. Unless you are playing real, authentic folk music, you probably won't play a lot of music that is truly pentatonic.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the name of the piece, which I have admitted in a comment might be a massive help...

The initial notes *are* in the C major/A minor pentatonic scale, but **note how Bar 1 switches to the F major/D minor pentatonic scale partway through and how Bar 2 is entirely in the F major/D minor pentatonic scale**.

I'm willing to believe that your musical excerpt is part of an etude that *specifically* targets switching pentatonic scales.

(The melody of Stephen Foster's "Oh! Susanna" behaves similarly, with all melody notes belonging to the starting note's major pentatonic scale except for the pesky first 2 notes of the chorus, which similarly use the subdominant note/scale degree. Think nearly all of the melody being in C major pentatonic, except for "Oh! Su-" being both F's.)

Comment: And if you don't exclude the harmony for Oh Susanna (which you shouldn't) you will also get the leading tone in the dominant chords, at which point it you have the full diatonic gamut and it becomes clear that song is not pentatonic music.

Answer (score 3):

'C pentatonic'. The notes you can mindlessly play over a C major chord without sounding wrong.   An earlier generation of improvisers thought of this in terms of 'avoid notes', the 'scale of the chord' minus notes a semitone away from chord notes.  Same result.  C major scale minus F and B.

Major 7ths are no longer considered particularly dissonant, so the only 'avoid note' left is the 4th.

This lick has all the notes of an F major scale except the 4th (B♭).  So you could put a 'F'  chord symbol over it, and no-one would say it was wrong.   (Or maybe a 'Fmaj7' if we didn't quite feel ready to admit E to full harmonic status in 'F'.)

BUT.....

Don't fall into the trap of confusing a framework with a prohibition.    'F' would be just as valid a chord symbol and harmonic analysis of this lick even if it contained - well, ANY other note than the F, G, A, C, D, E framework.

BUT BUT...

I agree with  @Dekkadeci, this could well be an exercise for guitarists about switching between C and F pentatonic scales.

BUT BUT BUT...

Do try to get out of that mindset.   You can make better music than just noodling on the 'safe' notes!

Answer (score 1):

The key signature is D minor, meaning probably it's a solo using D minor rather than D major (there's certainly no F♯ notes there). It may well be played over chords that fit the key of D major, but that's commonplace, and has worked well for decades.

And because there's an F♮ in that key, you wouldn't expect to find F♯ played. I guess we'd call it *borrowed* from its parallel key.

There's no reason on earth that all notes *have* to belong to a key. In fact, just about all 12 chromatic notes can and do come out to play in many, many pieces. With little or no justification needed. I posed a question regarding this matter a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I have to admit that, the way you phrased that question, it didn't encourage me at all to think of tonal music with all 12 notes in the chromatic scale (e.g. "You Will Know Our Names" from *Xenoblade Chronicles*, fairly sound fan agreement that it's in B flat minor, my absolute pitch concurs) - it encouraged me to think of tonal music that gets labelled as being in one key yet blatantly does not end in the key it starts in.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - what I was trying to do, and maybe it didn't come over as such, was to ask folk to not ask questions such as this. There seems to be something , possibly that's taught (wrongly) that pieces must have diatonic notes and having chromatics in them needs justification, but maybe my question didn't put that thinking over as well as it could have. I hope you understand where it was actually coming from. I just couldn't encapsulate what I wanted without sounding too dismissive.

Comment: My answer to your question leaned fairly hard into the fact that many pieces literally have their (supposedly) singular keys in their names (e.g. the celebrated Minuet in G (Major) found in the Anna Magdalena Notebook). Understandably, people will think such pieces will/may actually stick to the diatonic notes of that key.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - and most of the great composers fortify and sustain(ed) the myth - 'Concerto in x, Symphony in x', most of which will modulate a good few times, and so won't actually be in x all through. My point exactly.

Comment: Ah.  The revolt against 'guitar theory' grows.  Good!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I've been revolting most of my life - just ask those who know me...

Comment: A piece being "in key X" doesn't in any way mean it stays entirely in that one key. In fact most pieces, even very short pieces do not do that. Why would anyone but a total, absolute beginner think that? The only thing being "in key X" means is conventionally the music will start and end in that key, until you get to the 19th century, at which point the conventions changed.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - in that case, we have an awful lot of total, absolute beginners thinking that. Hence all the questions, and my previous one to try to stem the flow!

Comment: Actually, I've heard this misconception mostly from some of the top reputation members of the site. You literally need to completely ignore all descent harmony teaching or the entirety of common practice music to have this misunderstanding. Even basic exposure to blues and rock will introduce you to tones beyond pentatonic/diatonic. You need to ignore nearly everything you encounter in music to have this misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - so, my next question may be - why do folk hang on to this misconception - maybe a corollary of my last. On this site, we really need to expunge this bit of theory, don't we?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - I think part of why the misconception stays is because many, many measures straight of music from classical to pop to folk to children's songs to Christmas carols to national anthems is entirely diatonic in one key. This includes entire children's songs and Christmas carols (e.g. "B-I-N-G-O", "London Bridge Is Falling Down", "Joy to the World"). Honestly, if it isn't for the truck driver's gear changes in many Celine Dion songs, they'd actually be diatonic in one key. (Heck, I think "It's All Coming Back to Me Now" remains in diatonic C major throughout.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci - the US national anthem modulates for a moment (2nd line), although a guitarist once told me it was actually in Lydian..!  But you're right, the vast majority of stuff *is* diatonic - which doesn't mean the 'rules' say everything has to be.

Comment: Did someone say there are no purely diatonic melodies? Yes, lots of nursery rhyme melodies, some folk tunes, etc. are purely diatonic. Now look at a beginner method, like Clementi's Introduction to...Piano, where lesson 4 of 50 is when key changes are introduced. That would be typical. Re. X-Mas carols, my book 0785811990, starts with We Wish You a Merry Christmas w/ accidental in accompaniment, second song Deck the Halls w/ accidental in the melody. A person would need to have very little music experience and willful disregard of music education to have this misconception of diatonic.

Comment: Probably the fastest way to disabuse someone of this diatonic misconception is to have them play even simple music in a minor key. _Greensleeves_ for example. Seriously, how low are we setting the bar? The only other thing I can think of is students who encounter this music, but whose teachers don't teach the harmony theory. I had 4 years of guitar lessons with zero theory. I had to teach myself the theory long after those lessons.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - so I keep asking myself - why are there so many questions  very closely related to this? The answer may be that some take early music lessons, then stop, and feel they have enough theory, till this sort of thing jumps up at them.

Comment: I think your on the right track there, could be an age thing. Not sure the best age to introduce theory, 13 years old maybe. Surely there should be stages of theory and learning keys should come early. My guitar lessons ended around 14 years old. I should have gotten _some_ theory by then, at least keys, and tonic/dominant harmony concepts. That wouldn't have been overwhelming.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - never had guitar lessons, but have given them for best part of 50 yrs - but tended to do theory lessons as separate entities, mainly for exam purposes. But music theory is always intrinsically linked, so students get it, but probably don't realise! Never, ever taught the rule about having to stay diatonic, though..!

Comment: @Tim - I was not told that the Royal Conservatory of Music offers music theory lessons until I was in junior high school (Grades 7-9). (I essentially got to skip rudiments, though!) I therefore strongly suspect that many of my peers who took piano lessons never took music theory lessons in their entire lives. (I also heard that my brother stopped taking piano lessons in Grade 8.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) C major contains no sharps no flats (2) Key signature shows 1 flat which has to be B flat which means you're in the key of F, you have no choice you have to play the F natural in the phrase